# Scroll to specific element using mousewheel and DOMMouseScroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, mousewheel

I'm trying to scroll between divs vertically with the mousewheel event in Chrome and the DOMMouseScroll event in firefox. It's working fine in firefox, but in chrome it gets stuck after the first scroll step. Here's my code for scroll down same thing I'm using to scroll up with inverted marks.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){

    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 || event.originalEvent.detail > 0 && $('body,html').scrollTop() == $('#ctverec1').offsetTop )
    {
          $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $('#ctverec2').offsetTop},400 );
    }

    else if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 || event.originalEvent.detail > 0 && $('body,html').scrollTop() == $('#ctverec2').offsetTop)
    {
          $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $('#ctverec3').offsetTop},400 );                    
    }

   return false; 

});
```

Comment: of course but can you be more exact what you mean by that?

Comment: Simply that you mis-tagged your question for [tag:java] which will attract folks that understand this language, but who likely will not understand the language that this question involves -- [tag:javascript]. Someone has changed this for you today, but in the future, you will want to be careful about this so as to get the right experts to review your question, getting you better help, that's all.

Comment: sorry youre right my mistake